# DynamoDB managing list size by update-expression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

According to AWS docs, we can remove list items using next way

[Update expression - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE)

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"Id":{"N":"789"}}' \
    --update-expression "REMOVE RelatedItems[1], RelatedItems[2]" \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

The question is: Is there any possibility to remove all list items with index greater than 10?

Maybe something like:

```
--update-expression "REMOVE RelatedItems[10..]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such update expression.

For large scale manipulations people sometimes get the item then reinsert it with all the adjustments made, possibly with a condition expression to ensure the item hadn’t been modified in the meanwhile.